# I'm trying to set Backgrounds to 15 buttons and i'm having the skipping frame problems. Should I use threads somewhere ? (I'm new to Android)

Tags: java, android, performance

When I'm removing the `button.setBackgroundResource` line, it seems to fix my problem so I'm looking for help since I need them!

```
private void feedButtonWithRandomImages(){

    arrayOfImageCount = arrayOfImagesId.length;
    //type fori for autocomplete for loop
    for (i = 0; i < arrayOfImageCount;) {
                randomIndex = random.nextInt(arrayOfImageCount);
                if (!randomIndexList.contains(randomIndex)) {
                    randomIndexList.add(randomIndex);
                    int id = getResources().getIdentifier("btnSeekAndFind" + i, "id", getPackageName());
                    button = (Button) findViewById(id);
                    button.setBackgroundResource(arrayOfImagesId[randomIndex]);
                    button.setTag(thingsToFind[randomIndex]);
                    i++;
                    button.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                            String backgroundId = v.getTag().toString();
                            v.getBackground();
                            int newBackgroundId = findPressedImage(backgroundId);


                            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                                blopsound.start();
                                v.setBackgroundResource(arrayOfImagesIdPressed[newBackgroundId]);
                            } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                                if (!isGoodAnswer(backgroundId)) {
                                    v.setBackgroundResource(arrayOfImagesId[newBackgroundId]);
                                } else {
                                    v.setEnabled(false);
                                    getRandomWord();
                                    onSpeech(0);
                                }
                            }
                            return true;
                        }
                    });
                }

            }
    }`.
```

Comment: Your indexs may repeat, since they are random. So your may end up having more than 15 iterations and so spending more time on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few performance issues I found:

1. Try to use Set instead of List, it will get rid of duplicates automatically and save some method calls.
2. If buttons count is fixed, try to extract them from layout outside your loop (possibly in different lifecycle callback). `findViewById()` is considered expensive by some...
3. You don't really need to instantiate new OnTouchListener on every loop cycle. You can use single listener and tags to distinguish between different items.

In addition, try to use [profiling tools](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/traceview.html) to measure number and duration of method calls.

Comment: The profiling tools helped me a lot and also removing the OnTouchListener seems to have helped. Thanks.